# Kotlin not executable

Tags: kotlin

[image: Kotlin screenshot]
Hi, I tested a simple Kotlin program but it does not print out anything. What would be the causes? Thanks.

Comment: [Don't post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin scripts (.kts) don't use a main function. You just put the code directly in the file at the top level. So your code declares an arbitrary function named `main` but doesn't call it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it has `.kt` extension under `src\main\kotlin`.

[image]

For more information: https://github.com/halilozel1903/KotlinTutorials